# Autolayout issues with UITableView Footer, Storyboards, and Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

I'm attempting to add a footer view to my UITableView via the Storyboard, but Autolayout keeps drawing the footer view much larger than I've sized the view in the Storyboard. This seems to be caused by the Autolayout constraints on the UIButton contained within the footer view, though no combination of constraints (and I've tried several) results in the footer view sizing correctly, even when I get the UIButton sized correctly within the footer view.

A screenshot of the issue (the footer view has a white background) : [image: imgur link]

The constraints that I used in this particular instance (though keep in mind, I have tried several, including those with a defined height for the UIButton - when I set the UIButton's height the UIButton draws correctly, but the footer view is still enormous for some reason):

[image: constraints]

Thoughts? Solutions? I have used footer views with Storyboards before using Storyboards without any issues, though never with size classes.

Comment: Update: The only programmatic way I can get the footer view to show the correct height is by setting the footer view's frame to the correct height in viewDidLayoutSubviews, further confirming that Autolayout is calculating the incorrect height for reasons that I can't fathom. The TableView still assumes a footer of the existing height, though, meaning this isn't a solution. Ideas?

Comment: What are you setting the footer's height to in the storyboard? It looks like you have it set to be huge there.

Comment: The footer height is set correct (44 points) - see the screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    var footerView  = self.tableView.tableFooterView! as UIView
    var frame       = footerView.frame

    frame.size.height = 30
    footerView.frame = frame

    self.tableView.tableFooterView! = footerView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It looks like a bug of Xcode when you have a navigation bar

i solve it this way...

```
footerView = tableView.tableFooterView
    tableView.tableFooterView = nil
    tableView.addSubview(footerView)
    footerView.frame.size.height = 100
```